# Replacement for Apache Sqoop?

Tags: linux, hadoop

[Sqoop is retired](https://attic.apache.org/projects/sqoop.html)

What is a good alternative to Sqoop for regular bulk loads to HDFS from a SQL DBMS (Postgres and SQL Server)? I'd like support for splitting across multiple nodes, updating the Hive metastore, loading partitioned tables and creating Parquet files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - https://bit-ly.ru/QdO89. StreamSets DataOps Platform is a cloud-native platform for managing data pipelines.

Comment: [StreamSets](https://streamsets.com/) looks interesting. Thank you.

Comment: The link does not work..

Answer (score 1):

Maby Apache Flume ?

It is a distributed, reliable, and available service for efficiently collecting, ...

[apache-flume](https://stackshare.io/apache-flume)

Comment: Thanks Cristián. Flume is good for logs and text files. I don't think it can be used to extract data from a SQL DBMS.